# How do I set a redirect for my root index.html in jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have jekyll-redirect-from plugin, but it only really works for pages that aren't my root homepage.

For example, if a user types in www.mywebsite.com/index.html I want it to redirect and display the URL as www.mywebsite.com

Everything I can find about this is focused on blog posts and other pages than the index. Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a redirect, because `www.mywebsite.com/index.html` and `www.mywebsite.com` are the same page. (The browser just shows the `index` file by default if you go to `www.mywebsite.com`.)

You need the browser to rewrite the URL, while remaining on the same page. You need to do this on the webserver.

**.htaccess**

If your site is on an Apache server and you have access to the server, you can use an `.htaccess` file to [rewrite the URL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) from `www.mywebsite.com/index.html` to `www.mywebsite.com`.

There are online .htaccess generators [like this one](http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/) that help get the syntax right.

There are similar methods for [rewriting URLs on nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) webservers.

**GitHub Pages**

If you're on a service like GitHub Pages, you can't use .htaccess. A free workaround is to use Netlify to deploy your site, because you can set up [redirects on Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/). Create a free account on Netlify and add a new site from GitHub there.

In the root of your repo, create a `netlify.toml` file containing this:

```
# Redirect /index.html to /
[[redirects]]
  from = "/index.html"
  to = "/"
```

Netlify will now handle that redirect.

Comment: Doesn't google consider www.mywebsite.com/index.html and www.mywebsite.com different pages and indexes them twice?

I am using github pages and jekyll, so there is no htaccess.

Comment: I doubt Google indexes twice, but I can't be sure. I've edited my answer to include an option for using Netlify as a workaround with GitHub Pages.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using Jekyll with Github pages, but I can't seem to get the redirect-from plugin to work on my homepage, it only works on sub pages. Enabling it for the homepage seems to send it in a loop where its trying to forward to itself non-stop. I also tried to use Cloudflare but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Have you tried the Netlify option as described in my answer? As I explained, you don't need a redirect, you need a URL rewrite, which is a different thing and does not actually redirect the page.

Comment: I am working on that now actually. Had to get rid of my cloudflare because that was messing with the DNS settings. Thanks for the suggestion!